# SSIS package using lookup and staging table

Tags: html

I have to create a SSIS Package that reads data from a CSV file , loads some column values into a table (X) The rest of the columns in table X are to be filled from another table .

I have two common columns in both tables .. description and code . Based on the Descrption and code , The rest of the columns are filled in the table . The Problem is I am getting multiple columns , one without updation and the other column after updation .

I hope I am clear .

Thanks ,

Comment: It is not clear from your question which help or question you have? Do you  get stuck somewhere or what?

Comment: I have a csv file which has 5 columns - description , code , date , vin_number , port of delivery . I have two tables events and models - Event has 8 columns - description , code , date , vin_number , port of delivery , length , width and height . Models table has description , code , length, height and width as columns . I have to create a SSIS package which reads from CSV file and populate Events table for those 5 columns and the rest of the columns are populated from models table based upon decription and code . I hope I am clear now . I am very new to SSIS , so I will need help from start

Comment: I suggest you to start learning SSIS with taking SSIS course from microsoft or just google some good manual for SSIS, like this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155829/SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-Part-Basics On SO we usually answer specific questions related to specific dificulties user encountered (like this part of code is not working etc), not some general guidence

Comment: Hi , I am getting an error after I try to load my data into an oledb destination . Error- "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_JLR_EVENTS'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.JLR_EVENTS'   SSIS Package loads remaining fields of the table based upon a lookup between the source and destination tables

Comment: it has nothin to do with SSIS. You put a constraint for unique primary key I'm table JLR_EVENTS and you violate it with your SSIS